# I have a "Upload Record" PXAction to load records to grid and release these records

Tags: grid, acumatica

I have a custom PXbutton called UploadRecords, when I click this button I should populate the grid with records and release the records.
Release Action is pressed in the UploadRecords action delegate. The problem I get with this code is, the code here function properly for less records by release action but when passes thousands of records to release, it takes huge time(> 30 min.) and show the error like Execution timeout.
suggest me to avoid more execution time and release the records fastly.

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARPriceWorksheetMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARPriceWorksheetMaint>
    {
        //public class string_R112 : Constant<string>
        //{
        //    public string_R112()
        //        : base("4E5CCAFC-0957-4DB3-A4DA-2A24EA700047")
        //    {
        //    }
        //}

        public class string_R112 : Constant<string>
        {
            public string_R112()
                : base("EA")
            {
            }
        }

        public PXSelectJoin<InventoryItem, InnerJoin<CSAnswers, On<InventoryItem.noteID, Equal<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>,
            LeftJoin<INItemCost, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INItemCost.inventoryID>>>>,
            Where<InventoryItem.salesUnit, Equal<string_R112>>> records;

        public PXAction<ARPriceWorksheet> uploadRecord;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Upload Records", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
        public IEnumerable UploadRecord(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
            {
                foreach (PXResult<InventoryItem, CSAnswers, INItemCost> res in records.Select())
                {
                    InventoryItem invItem = (InventoryItem)res;
                    INItemCost itemCost = (INItemCost)res;
                    CSAnswers csAnswer = (CSAnswers)res;
                    ARPriceWorksheetDetail gridDetail = new ARPriceWorksheetDetail();
                    gridDetail.PriceType = PriceTypeList.CustomerPriceClass;
                    gridDetail.PriceCode = csAnswer.AttributeID;
                    gridDetail.AlternateID = "";
                    gridDetail.InventoryID = invItem.InventoryID;
                    gridDetail.Description = invItem.Descr;
                    gridDetail.UOM = "EA";
                    gridDetail.SiteID = 6;
                    InventoryItemExt invExt = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(invItem);

                    decimal y;

                    if (decimal.TryParse(csAnswer.Value, out y))
                    {
                        y = decimal.Parse(csAnswer.Value);
                    }
                    else
                        y = decimal.Parse(csAnswer.Value.Replace(" ", ""));

                    gridDetail.CurrentPrice = y; //(invExt.UsrMarketCost ?? 0m) * (Math.Round(y / 100, 2));
                    gridDetail.PendingPrice = y; // (invExt.UsrMarketCost ?? 0m)* (Math.Round( y/ 100, 2));
                    gridDetail.TaxID = null;
                    Base.Details.Update(gridDetail);
                }
                ts.Complete();
            }

            Base.Document.Current.Hold = false;
            using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
            {
                Base.Release.Press();
                ts.Complete();
            }
            List<ARPriceWorksheet> lst = new List<ARPriceWorksheet>
            {
                Base.Document.Current
            };
            return lst;
        }
        protected void ARPriceWorksheet_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
            var row = (ARPriceWorksheet)e.Row;

            uploadRecord.SetEnabled(row.Status != SPWorksheetStatus.Released);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone answer this question. I am waiting for someone to answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, Do you need them all to be in a single transaction scope? This would revert all changes if there is an exception in any. If you need to have them all committed without any errors rather than each record, you would have to perform the updates this way.

I would suggest though moving your process to a custom processing screen. This way you can load the records, select one or many, and use the processing engine built into Acumatica to handle the process, rather than a single button click action. Here is an example: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/creating-custom-processing-screens-in-acumatica/

Based on the feedback that it must be all in a single transaction scope and thousands of records, I can only see two optimizations that may assist. First is increasing the Timeout as explained in this blog post. https://acumaticaclouderp.blogspot.com/2017/12/acumatica-snapshots-uploading-and.html

Next I would load all records into memory first and then loop through them with a ToList(). That might save you time as it should pull all records at once rather than once for each record.

going from

```
foreach (PXResult<InventoryItem, CSAnswers, INItemCost> res in records.Select())
```

to

```
var recordList = records.Select().ToList();
foreach (PXResult<InventoryItem, CSAnswers, INItemCost> res in recordList)
```

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank for your reply KRichardson. I want all the records to be processed in a single transaction scope. And i dont want to use a new custom  processing screen here.

Comment: I have updated my answer with thoughts on optimizing requiring single threading.

Comment: I did the change  execution time out in web.config file but how do I include this web.config file into a customization package. I tried to add web.config file from "files" in Customization Project Editor. but dont see the  web.config file.